# Font CSS being overridden

Tags: css, fonts, size

I am currently making a website and having trouble with font sizes. You can see a demo of what I've done at [www.dweeman.com](http://www.dweeman.com). It is happening with the phone number font size at the top right and the copyright information in the bottom left. The CSS for them both is as follows:

```
p.copyright {size: 0.2em;}
p.phone {size: 0.75em;}
```

However it seems like something else in my CSS is overriding their.

I am using third party code for my navigation. I can't see anything in the CSS that would be doing this and was looking for another eye.

You can see all this on my test website I mentioned above, but if needed I can post my stylesheet here (it is quite long).

Thanks

Comment: Those selectors don't match any element on that page. You should use the `ID selector`, like `#phone`.

Comment: First of all, you are using the wrong CSS attribute.  Make sure to use font-size: instead of size.  I would also look into using pixels instead of em to size your font.  Good luck!

Comment: Gee what a stupid mistake to make. Is there any reason px is preferable to em with font size?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few issues with your site. And I really suggest reading up on how CSS selectors work. But in answer to your question.

You've set phone and copyright to have IDs. eg:

```
<p id="phone">
```

But in your CSS you've applied styles to the CLASS phone.

Change your respective P tags to:

```
 <p class="phone"> Foo </p>
```

Comment: Yeah I know, it's still in a very rough stage. I'm trying to get all the dimensions sorted out, and I'm relatively new to the whole process.

That's an annoying error that I should have noticed though. However even after changing it to class, they are still the same size. 

Were there any particularly noticeable errors you saw?